# Running gogs as nginx subdomain

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to run gogs off of my nas. I run other stuff off my nas, so I decided to make gogs a subdomain. Here is what I tried:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name gogs.nas.me;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3237;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_buffering off;
        }
}
```

I do not have a domain name for it, but I have `nas.me` pointing towards `192.168.0.120` in `/etc/hosts`.

When I go to `gogs.nas.me`, I get `gogs.nas.me’s server DNS address could not be found.` When I go to `nas.me`, I get the index of my nas. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I also tried using `nas.me/gogs`, which worked but all of the assets did not get the `/gogs` prefix so I got 404s on everything but `/`.

Comment: The answer lies in the error description `gogs.nas.me’s server DNS address could not be found.` It means you do not have a DNS record for the subdomain.

Comment: @IVOGELOV How would I add this?

Comment: The easiest way for you is to add `gogs.nas.me` in `/etc/hosts` on the same row as `nas.me` - providing that this file is on your laptop and NOT on the NAS itself.

Comment: I have tried that. No luck.

Comment: Can you show the file content ? It is pretty straight forward ... You should be able to ping the host by either of its names.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Here is the file: `127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 Zeus

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.0.120 nas.me
192.168.0.120 gogs.nas.me`

http://pastebin.com/uCZqz1D6

Comment: The last line should be `192.168.0.120 nas.me gogs.nas.me` Please look at this answer - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102663

Comment: I will try that when I get home. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @IVOGELOV We are making progress. With both on one line, I get a new error message: `gogs.nas.me refused to connect.` Going to `192.168.0.120:3237` works as expected as well as `nas.me:3237`.

Comment: What application do you run on port 3237 ? And what is "gogs" actually ? Have you looked in the eror log of nginX ?

Comment: [gogs](https://gogs.io/) is a git server that runs on port 3237 by default. Nothing in the nginx access log or journalctl.

Comment: If you can ping `gogs.nas.me` this means your DNS is working as desired. Now you have to find out why HTTP connections get refused - you need to define `access_log` and `error_log` directives inside the `server` section and also check how the GOGS logging works. You need to look what both nginX and GOGS are complaining about - in their log files. I can not tell what exactly to look for, but log files are the key here.

Comment: @IVOGELOV It's working now. Seems I just had to restart my computer. Weird. Anyway, post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `gogs.nas.me` to the file `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
192.168.0.120  nas.me gogs.nas.me
```

Both names should be on the same line, otherwise there will be wrong behavior (look at this answer - [unix.stackexchange.com/a/102663](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102663))
Usually adding a new DNS entry in `/etc/hosts` does not need restarting - but just to be safe, you can do a restart.